# How to zip a file in Debian using bash with a single directory popping when unzipping

Tags: bash, makefile, zip

I am attempting to zip a directory called "project" into a .zip file called "BARBIER_MAM.zip". However, when unzipping the .zip file, all the files contained show up and I have to manually put them back in a directory.
Here is how I currently do. In the "project" directory, I have a makefile with an "archive" target :

```
archive: clean
    zip -r BARBIER_MAM.zip .
```

I have also tried :

```
archive: clean
    cd ..
    zip -r BARBIER_MAM.zip project
```

But I got an error :

```
zip warning: name not matched: project
```

In case you would be asking, yes, it has to be done in the makefile contained in the directory that has to be zipped.

Comment: Why the C tag?  Why not Bash and Makefile instead?

Comment: Have you tried `project/*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipes)(emphasis mine):

> When it is time to execute recipes to update a target, they are executed by invoking **a new sub-shell for each line** of the recipe, unless the .ONESHELL special target is in effect (see Using One Shell) (In practice, make may take shortcuts that do not affect the results.)
>
> Please note: this implies that **setting shell variables and invoking shell commands such as cd that set a context local to each process will not affect the following lines in the recipe**. If you want to use cd to affect the next statement, put both statements in a single recipe line.

So in your second example, change that to:

```
archive: clean
    cd .. && zip -r BARBIER_MAM.zip project
```